# Cannot setup ssh gateway

Tags: linux, ssh, gateway

I am trying to setup a ssh gateway. I have a physical host (H) and a number of VMs on it. The host can ssh to one of the VMs (A) and then ssh to others from it (lets call it B). I have this in `.ssh/config` in H

```
Host B
  User foo
  ProxyCommand ssh foo@A nc %h %p
```

Now when I do `ssh -vvv -l foo B` on `H` I see this error: `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

`cat /var/log/auth.log` on A says:

```
Jun  7 18:54:00 ubuntu sshd[846]: Received disconnect from 192.168.129.1: 11: disconnected by user
Jun  7 18:54:00 ubuntu sshd[834]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user foo
Jun  7 18:54:11 ubuntu sudo: foo : TTY=pts/6 ; PWD=/home/foo ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail /var/log/auth.log
Jun  7 18:54:11 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by foo(uid=30000)
```

`/etc/hosts.allow` on A

```
sshd: ALL
ssh: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
```

It seems H is saying that A closed the connection and A says that H closed the connection!

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on `H`

```
Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

What else can go wrong here?

Comment: You using ssh keys?  Your key could be wrong.  Also iptables.

Comment: ssh keys are not wrong probably. I can login using the same keys by first logging in to A. iptables on all boxes are empty.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to make sure 'Host B' should not include A, if B is a pattern rather than a single host. I had to exclude A from the pattern explicitly.

```
Host *.example.com !gateway.example.com
  ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p user_on_gateway@gateway.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following configuration in H host:

```
Host B
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p A
```

It is working for me. Just add user foo if you need:

```
Host B
    User foo
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p foo@A
```

And make sure that user foo exists on A and B.

Comment: I tried this and got the same error. User foo does exist on all boxes, I can login to B from A using the same credentials.

Comment: What about /etc/ssh/sshd_config content on all hosts? 
PasswordAuthentication paremeters? etc...

Comment: Nothing that I noticed. Updated the question with it's contents.